# Find a value in a nested 2d array of objects and remove the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a nested array like this:

```
array = [
  [
    'Bear',
    [
      {
        name: 'bob',
        age: '17,'
      },
      {
        name: 'sam',
        age: '18,'
      },
    ],
  ],
  [
    'dog',
    [
      {
        name: 'bon',
        age: '19,'
      },
    ],
  ],
];
```

I need to delete/remove this object: 
{
            name: 'bon',
            age: '19,'
          },
If the array above has not objects, then the array above, which in this case is dog, should be removed aswell
What's the cleanest way to do this? I have tried filter, but to no avail. Not sure how to do this in a clean way. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the criteria for removing it?

Comment: How do you idenfity the object ? Do you mean delete all objects with name bon and age 19 ? or only first occurence ?

Comment: it will be based on the name value, if name === 'bon', delete that object. If there is only one object in that array, the array gets removed aswell

Comment: Will the structure be the same ? Array will always be a tuple having string at index 0 and another array of objects at index 1 ?

Comment: somehow i need to find the value of 'bon' in this nested array and delete it

Comment: @DhananjaiPai yes, structure will always be the same

Comment: I'm not sure why you selected the wrong answer as the one you used since it doesn't do as you asked. Did you try with `[['dog', [{name: 'bon', age: '19'},{name: 'other', age: '19'}]]]`? Does the whole `['dog',[{name...}]] ` item need to be removed when the `[{name:...]]` list is empty or only the list itself? So does `[['dog', [{name: 'bon', age: '19'}]]]` result in `[]` or in `['dog']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kept the key and value dynamic in case you should filter people based on age. It returns a new array with the results as expected.

```js
array = [
  ['Bear', [{name: 'bob', age: '17,'},{name: 'sam', age: '18,'}]],
  ['dog', [{name: 'bon', age: '19'}]],
];

function customFilter(array,key,value) {
    return array.filter(([animal,list]) => {
      list = list.filter(item => item[key] !== value);
      if(list.length == 0)
        return false;
      return true;
    });
}

console.log(customFilter(array,'name','bon'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove items if `name === 'bon'` and then want to remove the sibling array based on the count of the filter, you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
const array = [['Bear',[{name:'bob',age:'17,'},{name:'sam',age:'18,'},],],['dog',[{name:'bon',age:'19,'}]]];
const name = 'bon';

const output = array.reduce((acc,[animal, people]) => {
  const filtered = people.filter(a => a.name !== name);
  if(filtered.length > 0) 
    acc.push([animal, filtered]);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: you must remove dog if the list is empty

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I misunderstood the comment OP wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the main array and filter out the items from the sub array, then map again to remove the list of items when it's empty:

```js
let array = [
  [
    'Bear',
    [
      {
        name: 'bob',
        age: '17,',
      },
      {
        name: 'sam',
        age: '18,',
      },
    ],
  ],
  [
    'dog',
    [
      {
        name: 'bon',
        age: '19,',
      },
    ],
  ],
];
console.log(
  array
    .map(([name, list]) => [
      name,
      list.filter((item) => item.name !== 'bon'),
    ])
    .map(
      //remove empty lists
      ([name, list]) =>
        list.length === 0 ? [name] : [name, list],
    ),
);
```

You can even pass in the filter function seperately:

```js
const array = [["Bear",[{"name":"bob","age":"17,"},{"name":"sam","age":"18,"}]],["dog",[{"name":"bon","age":"19,"}]]];

const filterBy = (arr, filterFunction) =>
  arr
    .map(([name, list]) => [
      name,
      list.filter(filterFunction),
    ])
    .map(
      //remove empty lists
      ([name, list]) =>
        list.length === 0 ? [name] : [name, list],
    );

console.log(filterBy(array, (item) => item.name !== 'bon'));
```

Comment: You are looping twice with map, you could use a single `filter` to loop once and improve performance

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Functions should do only one thing so they can be combined and re used in different ways. If you buy a toy helicopter it can only be a helicopter. If you have the lego blocks to make a helicopter you can make that or anything else you'd like to make. If you want to map only once you can pass fucntions that can be composed but in this case it should not matter. Readability and reusability is way more important than performance.

Comment: I did not ask you to write a for loop and do a thousand side effects inside! `filter` is meant to loop through the list one by one and filter based on a criteria. `map` is used to loop and cause a modification. All I meant to say was to use the concepts judiciously. Performance is very important in client side transpiled languages. A filter does not sacrifice the readability.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai You stopped making sense there. There is no loop nor are there any side effects. It you're worried about the double map you can do something like `arr.map(_.flow([filterList,removeEmptyList]))`

Comment: I was talking about the `functions should do only one thing` I didnt ask you to do multiple things. And exactly why would I want to add lodash to my project!?

Answer (score 0):

try This-

```
array = [
              [
                'Bear',
                [
                  {
                    name: 'bob',
                    age: '17,'
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'sam',
                    age: '18,'
                  },
                ],
              ],
              [
                'dog',
                [
                  {
                    name: 'bon',
                    age: '19,'
                  },
                ],
              ],
            ];

for(var i =0; i< array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][1].length);
    if(array[i][1].length <= 1){
        delete(array[i]);
    }
}
console.log(array);
```